# Apply pandoc_args to only part of an rmarkdown doc - eg two columns

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Is there a way to create an output with rmarkdown that only has two columns for *part* of the page? That is I want a header and some text that stretches across a whole page but the figures remain in column formats. Consider the example below where columns are set to 2 but the header remains in there.

#### Update

I got a bit closer here with the `\twocolumn` solution but then a new blank page is created.

````
---
title: "twocol_test"
author: "test"
output: pdf_document
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## This header should stretch across the whole page
Then this text should also not be in a column. But then the figures below should be organized into two columns:

\twocolumn

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

\onecolumn


```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````

More generally the question is how to apply a pandoc arg to only part of the `.Rmd` file?

Comment: A related question is "how to do that in LaTeX?" I will be surprised if markdown does *that* easily, but since you're creating a PDF, you can find the raw LaTeX and do that instead. (It's how I've rotated some pages but not all.)

Comment: I think the solution includes directly including some latex code but haven't been able to figure exactly which yet.

Comment: I suggest this would be answered faster at https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do they answer rmarkdown questions there? To be clear this is a rmarkdown question not a LaTeX question. Two columns in LaTeX is relatively trivial. It is how to make it work in rmarkdown.

Comment: They don't address (r)markdown much if at all, true, but I believe this is not possible with markdown. I think you'll have to put in raw LaTeX commands within the markdown file; pandoc should pass them through, and the `pdflatex` process should take over.

Comment: It think it is the interaction between rmarkdown and latex that is giving me issue here though. I can put a multicol environment in a .tex file no problem. The issue is that when I do that here it breaks whatever in rmarkdown generates `\includegraphics` which the throws an error. There is also the example above (updated) which I am not sure how to deal with.

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't with interaction between markdown and LaTeX, but between `\includegraphics` and the multi-column switching? I don't know a markdown-centric fix, but if you ask "over there", you may find some tex-friendly fixes.

Comment: Feet in both worlds eh? I can make a reproducible .tex file to do what I want but not an rmarkdown one. In LaTeX `\includegraphics` works fine with a multicol environment.

Comment: Have you kept all intermediate tex files to see what differences there are between markdown-rendered and you-rendered?

Comment: Have to love R: this package was placed on cran today and probably contains, if not the exact spes, code showing how to do this: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pinp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't exactly able to figure this out but found something that will work for my purposes that involves passing a parameter to the title which spans both columns. Not perfect but this will work:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "-V", "classoption=twocolumn"
    ]
params:
  test:
    value: test
  set_title: test_title
---

---
title: `r params$set_title`
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````